# Notice: Undefined index: uid in при запросе

Tags: mysql, pdo, php7

```
$SQLGetInfo = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
$SQLGetInfo->execute(array(':username' => $_GET['uid']));
$userInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Notice: Undefined index: uid in  выводит ошибку. в чем проблема?

Comment: В $_GET нет параметра uid

Comment: добавил параметр $username =  protect($_GET['uid']); 
все рано ошибка